# What to replace the function largo_enqueue_js with in order to display sticky_nav?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to make changes to an existing Wordpress theme (Largo) in order to permanently display the sticky navigation header. I've fixed everything else but this step:

- Replace the function largo_enqueue_js with a copy that sets the 'sticky_nav_display' and 'main_nav_hide_article' values to true:

```
    'sticky_nav_display' => (bool) of_get_option( 'sticky_nav_display', 0 ),
    'main_nav_hide_article' => (bool) of_get_option( 'main_nav_hide_article', 0 ),
```

How would I replace this function (full code [here](https://github.com/INN/largo/blob/187eca0be6a0fb04f35c3ee9ee18294435e4d276/inc/enqueue.php#L50-L51))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `wp_localize_script()` in a child theme to override the data set in the parent.  You just need this in your child theme

```
    wp_localize_script(
        'largoCore', 'Largo', array(
        'is_home' => is_front_page(),
        'is_single' => is_single() || is_singular(),
        'sticky_nav_options' => array(
            'sticky_nav_display' => true,
            'main_nav_hide_article' => true,
            'nav_overflow_label' => of_get_option( 'nav_overflow_label', 'More' )
        )
    ));
```